# c++ Array output has trash memory values

Tags: c++, arrays

I was making practice on arrays in c++ I got trash memory values, how can I fix it thanks

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fsream>
#include<iostream>
#include<locale.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

string sone;
string stwo;
string sthree;
string sfour;

int one;
int two;
int three;
int four;

int main(int org, char** argv)
{

    char array = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    while (four <= 10)
    {
        three = 0
        while (three <= 10)
        {
            two = 0
            while (two <= 10)
            {
                one = 0
                while (one <= 10)
                {
                    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Local");
                    ofstream out("file.txt", ios::app);
                    sone = array[one];
                    stwo = array[two];
                    sthree = array[three];
                    sfour = array[four];
                    out << sfour + sthree + stwo + sone;
                    out << "\n";
                    out.close();
                    one++;
                }
                two++;
            }
            four++;
        }
        five++;
    }
}
```

output:

```
1-aaaa   
2-aaab   
3-aaac   
4-aaad   
5-aaa#   
6-aaa?   
7-aaa0   
8-aaa#  
9-aaa'   
10-aaa_  
11-aaa?  
12-aaba  
13-aabb
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? what is your expected output?

Comment: Several bugs in the code. A few are simple typos, but `four` is not being initialized before use and seeing as it is the key to the `while` loop the output can be incredibly wacky.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable one,two,three,four have range from 1 to 10.
Where as your array is just 4 char. Your are accessing "array out of bounds"

Comment: just a minor correction, it's from 0 to 10 (values are incremented after usage). Doesn't change the main point of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you never set your into value of four equal to anything. Every time you call four++ its grabbing a random value.

Also, I'm not sure how you compiled this since there is not variable five and you are incrementing it.